# parse LocalStorage data into a a table dynamically

Tags: html, local-storage

I am really new to code (couple of weeks old actually). However, I seem to be stuck on an issue I just cant work out. I've basically built a small quiz game with scores that will add up at the end of each level and will store each levels score in local storage under the key (the username) and attached to that is a string. Once past all three levels, the system is set to add up scores from all levels and give it a total score. Again this is stored in local storage as a value for the key (the username). This basically enters data into the string in any random position.

This all seems to work fine. However I want to now retrieve these scores from localstorage and dynamically fill the table with these scores labelled by the username. I then want to rank these scores front highest to lowest as we go down the table. I feel like I just cant find a way to do this. Please help. :(

This is how it currently stores the information on localstorage for the two users (as two separate keys)

{un: "salman786", ea: "ab@ab.com", pass: "khan", L1 Score: 5, L2 Score: 3, L3 Score: 1, total: 9}
L1 Score: 5
L2 Score: 3
L3 Score: 1
ea: "ab@ab.com"
pass: "khan"
total: 9
un: "salman786"

{un: "so112", ea: "so@hotmail.co.uk", pass: "sad", L1 Score: 3, L2 Score: 2, L3 Score: 0, total: 5}
L1 Score: 3
L2 Score: 2
L3 Score: 0
ea: "so@hotmail.co.uk"
pass: "sad"
total: 5
un: "so112"

Comment: `This basically enters data into the string in any random position. `

This is how `key-value` storage works.

One plugin I will recommend is to use [nano-sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano-sql), it is a high level wrapper to LevelDB, IndexedDB, WebSQL for storage locally. With it you can do query like a real DB.

Comment: Thank you Tim. However I just want to use some JS code at the moment to retrieve the data onto a table dynamically. Meaning add a row of data for each user.